# Android WebView detection in PHP

Tags: php, android, webview

I've done a simple Android App with native menu and a webview with my site content. I need to detect if my website is included in a webview in order to hide the menu bar.

After a long research I found this way:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "myAppPackage"){
    //the site is included in webview
}
```

This solution is good for a lot of devices, but for a Galaxy S4 Mini(Android 4.2.2) this variable is blank!

Other htp header variables:

- PATH                   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
- UNIQUE_ID              U6LV8AAAEAABFtKXcAAADY
- HTTP_HOST              hostname
- HTTP_ACCEPT            text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
- HTTP_USER_AGENT        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116
  Safari/537.36
- HTTP_REFERER           http://webx225.aruba.it/CP/index.php
- HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING   gzip,deflate,sdch
- HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE   it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
- HTTP_COOKIE            PHPSESSID=5deb3527097d0f767aba45d0aa042; acopendivids=nada; acgroupswithpersist=nada; wooTracker=lzp5HpPQNDCd;
  __utma=250126209.968543423.1402584011.1403102882.1403106109.27; __utmc=250126209; __utmz=250126209.1402752662.8.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
- HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL max-stale=0
- HTTP_CONNECTION        Keep-Alive
- HTTP_X_BLUECOAT_VIA    b1ae316f3a2874e7
- SERVER_SIGNATURE       no value
- SERVER_SOFTWARE        Apache/2.2
- SERVER_NAME            hostname
- SERVER_ADDR            62.149.140.235
- SERVER_PORT            80
- REMOTE_ADDR            62.249.32.77
- DOCUMENT_ROOT          /web/htdocs/hostname/home/
- SERVER_ADMIN           postmaster@hostname
- SCRIPT_FILENAME        /web/htdocs/hostname/home/**aruba__php__test**.php
- REMOTE_PORT            43924
- GATEWAY_INTERFACE      CGI/1.1
- SERVER_PROTOCOL        HTTP/1.1
- REQUEST_METHOD     GET
- QUERY_STRING           no value
- REQUEST_URI            /**aruba__php__test**.php
- SCRIPT_NAME            /**aruba__php__test**.php
- PHPRC                  no value

Comment: the variable ib blank

Comment: What is phpinfo() telling of other variables?

Comment: in phpinfo() there is no HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH variable.

Comment: Think in the WebView code you can add "myAppPackage" to HTTP_USER_AGENT en check for that in php. Use `webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString(); ` and `webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(modifiedString);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to greenapps idea, this is the final solution.

**Android APP MainActivity**:

```
public View onCreateView
....

WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_webview);


String agentModified = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().concat(" MobileApplication(mypackage)");
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(agentModified);
```

**Web site**:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'com.vivicrema.android') !== false)
    $isMobileApp = true;
```

It works like a charm!