# How to detect pages when a user browses inside twitter in app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, browser

I want to be able to detect user when the user browses a web page inside twitter app. By detecting, I want to just add a body class that I will use to change the way the page looks for users inside twitter app. However, all my tries so far failed.

I can detect webview inside Facebook app using the following code

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
if ((ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1)) {
  return 'facebook';
}
```

I have looked around/ googled around/ checked other StackOverflow solutions. However, I could not find a solution where I can detect twitter in-app. That is, I want to detect when a user browses a page inside twitter app.

The things I have tried and failed are below

```
   if (/Twitter for/i.test(nua) === true) {
      return 'twitter';
   }
```

or

```
if (/\/\/t.co\//i.test(document.referrer) === true && /Safari\//.test(nua) === false) {
  return 'twitter';
}
```

or checking for the browser, device, vendor, model, device type, engine, os, os version (why was I checking this?!?). I checked using Modernizr; however, no difference was found between as standalone Safari and in-app Twitter. Also, checked using [Detect if user is using webview for android/iOS or a regular browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591279/detect-if-user-is-using-webview-for-android-ios-or-a-regular-browser)

Also tried the following with failure

```
   var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
      safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
      ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );

var standalone = window.navigator.standalone,
  userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
  safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
  ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );

if( ios ) {
  if ( safari ) {
    $('.debug').prepend('Yeah I am a browser in ios');
  } else if ( !safari ) {
    $('.debug').prepend('Yeah I am a webview in ios');
  }
} else {
  $('.debug').prepend('Yeah I am NOT a ios');
}

if( ios ) {
  if ( !standalone && safari ) {
    $('.debug').prepend('Yeah I am a browser in ios');
  } else if ( standalone && !safari ) {
    $('.debug').prepend('Yeah I am a standaline in ios');
  } else if ( !standalone && !safari ) {
    $('.debug').prepend('Yeah I am WEBVIEW');
  }
} else {
  $('.debug').prepend('Yeah I am NOT IOS');
}

var isWebView = !/safari/.test( window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) || navigator.platform === 'iOS' || navigator.platform === 'iPhone'
$('.debug').prepend('<br>isWebView? : ' + isWebView + "<br>");
$('.debug').prepend('<br>AM I WEBVIEW?: ' + /AppName\/[0-9\.]+$/.test(navigator.userAgent));

var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var is_safari_or_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
$('.debug').prepend('<br> is_uiwebview :' + is_uiwebview);
$('.debug').prepend('<br> is_safari_or_uiwebview :' + is_safari_or_uiwebview);


var uaSafari = navigator.userAgent.match(/Safari/i)
var uaSafariInput = navigator.userAgent.match(/Safari/i).input
var uaSafariIndex  = navigator.userAgent.match(/Safari/i).index
$('.debug').prepend('<br> ' + uaSafari + '<br>' + uaSafariInput + '<br>' + uaSafariIndex + '<br>' + navigator.vendor + '<br>' + navigator.product + '<br>' + navigator.productSub + '<br>' + navigator.languages.length + '<br>' + navigator.doNotTrack + '<br>' + navigator.maxTouchPoints + navigator.maxTouchPoints);

//Check headers and see if any difference there
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
$('.debug').prepend('<br> headers \t ' + headers);


if (/Twitter for/i.test(navigator.userAgent) === true) {
  $('.debug').prepend('<br> Test1 ');
}

$('.debug').prepend('<br> Document referrer is : '+ document.referrer + " <br> ");

if (/\/\/t.co\//i.test(document.referrer) === true && /Safari\//.test(navigator.userAgent) === false) {
  $('.debug').prepend('<br> Test2 ');
}
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't believe it's possible to detect the Twitter in-app browser in JavaScript, because it uses a generic Web View with no identifiable properties.

Most of your examples rely on searching the user agent string for specific keywords. Here's a comparison of user agent strings between the relevant browsers in iOS 11 for iPad based on a test I just conducted:

**Safari**

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5372a Safari/604.1`

**Facebook (in-app)**

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15A5372a [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/140.0.0.63.89;FBBV/70896504;FBDV/iPad4,2;FBMD/iPad;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/11.0;FBSS/2;FBCR/AT&T;FBID/tablet;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/5;FBRV/0]`

**Twitter (in-app)**

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5372a Safari/604.1`

You can see that Twitter's browser user agent is identical to Safari.

Obviously this is not a solution to your problem, but more of an explanation why you haven't found an actual answer.

Comment: That is very sad to know. :(

Comment: Apple don't authorise other browser engines on ios. Underneath they're all based on WebKit. That's why the user agent is exactly the same between apps. The twitter and facebook apps all use the same browser engine under the hood. Maybe change strategy and see if there are url parameters specific to the app in the page context or possibly even js variables. You'll have to dig for any differences. Alternatively @SwagatoBhatta could try browser fingerprinting, though it may not be reliable enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if navigator.mediaDevices is undefined. Since webRTC isn’t supported in webviews, it will be undefined in Twitter but present in Safari.

Comment: Elaborate more on your answer.

Comment: Answer is possibly related to this article? https://medium.com/@leemartin/in-app-browsers-i-forgive-thee-not-f87b25f9418e

Answer (score 0):

Twitter uses t.co to warp the shared URL, so there is a redirect before reaching the real content.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/tco

When checking all the headers sent from Twitter in-app browser, the referer header filed shows the wrapped t.co link.

```
referer: http://t.co/ 0JG5Mcq
```

Maybe this header can help distinguish with Safari's User-Agent.

Comment: It wont work because for desktop it is also the same referer