# How to find out the android app using your website as "Webview"?

Tags: webview, google-analytics, android-webview, progressive-web-apps

My mobile website is getting alot of traffic from browser "Webview" in Google Analytics. I believe some app is using my website as a "Webview".

Is there any way I can find out the app's package name. The main reason to find out the app is to make sure the ads are being displayed properly and not being altered in any way.

Comment: Have you been able to visit this [SO post(Detect if user is using webview for android/iOS or a regular browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591279/detect-if-user-is-using-webview-for-android-ios-or-a-regular-browser)?

Comment: Yes, this above answer lets you detect whether the visitor is from webview or regular browser. I am interested in finding the package id of android app using the webview for my website.