# Show div on android devices

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

is it possible to have a div tag that is visible only in specific devices?
i want show a div just in browser android devices, and dont show this div in webview android.

```
<div class="android-devices"><a href="#">Android user please click here to download application</a></div>
```

Is this possible? I use wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with javascript.

Firstly add `hide` class to all your `android-devices` divs

And add this code to your css file:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

And add this to your javascript file

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.android-devices');
  els.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('hide');
  })
}
```

This code will detect android devices and will remove the `hide` classes from your divs.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to hide some divs on android, you can apply same logic.

Just use this line

```
el.classList.add('hide');
```

instead of this

```
el.classList.remove('hide');
```

And don't add `hide` class to your `android-devices` divs by default.

Comment: Also i what (dont show) this div in webview android.
is it possible?

Comment: Thanks Solhan. But I want to display this Div on (Android browsers) but not display on (Android Webview)

Comment: For detecting webview or browser you should check header of the request. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37705154/7971182)

Comment: this answer worked for ios. Can you write the full code for Android in a new post here? and "your.app.id" is my package name android app?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going through following steps

### - Setting div to hidden initially ( HTML part )

```
  <div class="android-devices hide"><a href="#">Android user please click here to download application</a></div>
```

### - Checking if current device is android device, if it is then show div ( JS part )

```
var isDeviceAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if( isDeviceAndroid  ){document.getElementsByClassName('android-devices').classList.remove("hide");
```

}

### - Css part

.hide{display:none;}