# Mute WebView when it's visibility is gone

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I want to load an URL in my WebView and show it to the user when reaching that stage. So I call the **loadUrl** method and set my WebView visibility gone until I want to show it to the user. The problem is that each time the URL I load in my WebView has the sound it starts to play even when the WebView is invisible. What should I do to mute and unmute WebView?

Comment: Its better if you disable it by webpage as per the Client. Something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591279/detect-if-user-is-using-webview-for-android-ios-or-a-regular-browser) i am not sure if its a full proof solution for detection  or not.

Comment: No, I need the ability to unmute the webpage. @ADM