# How to use SvelteKit to create a multi platform offline, online, WebView, Browser app?

Tags: web-applications, webview, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I'm looking to use C# Xamarin together with SvelteKit to create a multiplatform app that will run in a native web view as well as in a browser.

How do I go about using SvelteKit to create an app for the WebView? I'd like to download all the required parts of the web app onto the device and run those files inside a WebView, so that the GUI and the app are available offline.

Maybe there's a built in sveltekit command for this, or maybe I just copy the files from the normal build?

Also what's the best way to figure out whether the app is running in a webview or a browser?

Comment: Webview: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591279/detect-if-user-is-using-webview-for-android-ios-or-a-regular-browser

Comment: Generating the app: Have a look at adapter-static, you can create SPAs with it.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I'm looking for is not currently available for SvelteKit. https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/907. But adapter-static is the closes option I have, so thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Keep it simple, make it easy for your viewers?  Progressive Web App (PWA) in Sveltekit. Responsive for mobile and desktop. Less work for you too.