# Are there any properties or headers in a response that record whether a request comes from Mobile vs Desktop implementations?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I want to be able to know whether my plugin gets called from Banno Mobile or Banno Desktop implementation. I would like to know if there is a Consumer API property or custom header that determines whether a request to retrieve my plugin comes from Banno Mobile or Banno Desktop implementations.

I know I could always implement a media query, always parse the user agent to get the information and sometimes leverage the Sec-CH-UA-Mobile header to cleanly differentiate between mobile/desktop. I just wanted to know if there's a property, header or some other part of the Consumer APIs that tells which implementation the request comes from that I'm missing.

Otherwise, I'll likely just use a mix of the aforementioned header parsing.

Thanks team!

Comment: There isn't such a thing provided. See answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73295730/how-to-determine-if-user-is-in-a-webview-in-a-jack-henry-banno-mobile-app/73296217

Comment: (Btw, mods, that other question doesn't have an accepted answer so folks are unable to mark this one as a duplicate)

Comment: you could sniff the user agent, sniff the header, or do a media query. We don't have specific guidance on this topic and the platform itself doesn't provide specific context via any means.