How to target only webview rendering with CSS?
The website in question renders correctly on various Firefox browsers, Mac, and IOS browsers, Edge, Chrome, and Chromium, on both desktop and mobile.
However, when it is viewed from webview, either from a link clicked on android facebook app, or even actually the duck duck go mobile android app, one of the font sizes is larger and pushes outside of its container div, breaking the view.
I've been developing front-end for 10 years, but have yet to explore any webview customizations.
How to target webview rendering from CSS (or if need be JavaScript)?

As far as I know, There is no way to target webviews only

But what can you do is check if the not working webview if it has a custom user agent and use that for conditional css styling

There's a reasonable number of clicks from Facebook mobile. Enough that it would make sense to adjust the view on the other browsers to satisfy WebView. However, the font-size setting on body tag is left to the browser. Every section uses a responsive calc/range mix-in in rems, elements under sections inherit from the mix-in in ems. Browsers set a default font-size on the body tag, WebView could be doing that differently, but then all of the fonts would be differently sized. Also, chrome debug facebook android device doesn't pick it up. Can you provide a link with WebView details?

One reply was removed, it was the best answer to the question I was asking, but, it was faster for me anyway to change the font size for all browser to get the web view typeface to fit the nav container also on web, which is what I suggested in comment above and what the response below suggested. This link suggested by another user is also comprehensive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591279/detect-if-user-is-using-webview-for-android-ios-or-a-regular-browser

To solve the problem of your website looking odd in certain mobile apps, like Facebook or DuckDuckGo on Android, you can try adjusting its appearance using CSS first. If that doesn't work, you can use JavaScript to figure out if it's being viewed in one of those apps and then change how it looks. It's important to test these changes in different apps to make sure everything looks right. By combining CSS and JavaScript tricks, you can hopefully fix the problem and make sure your website looks good no matter where it's viewed from.

This reads like chatGPT response. Also, the error shows on the browser facebook uses when viewers click on a link on the mobile app, which as I understand is not the facebook app, but its webview component.
